# jquery append and not being able to click the appended class

Tags: jquery, onclick, append

I have a div which when click a new div is appened - when this new div is shown and wants to be closed by clicking on it, it does fire.

This is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/foba81eb/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    $('.one').click(function() {
    if (counter <= 0) {
        $('p').append("<p id='closingCross'>X</p>");
        counter++;
    }
});
  $('#closingCross').click(function() {
    //This is not firing?!
    alert("hello");
  });
});
```

I just want it to close on click but it is doing nothing?

What am I doing wrong here?

Cheers,

Ben.

P.S - have a look at the updated fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/foba81eb/4/

when I .hide() and then click to get it back it doesn't work!!

Comment: I've not found it possible to do this as when the document is ready, the dynamic content does not yet exists. Try having the content exist but hide it. (CSS display:none)

Comment: Write `$(document).on("click", "#closingCross", function() {..` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="one">
<p>
hello world
</p>
<p id='closingCross' style="display:none">X</p>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


var counter=0;

$('.one').click(function() {
if(counter <= 0){
  $('p').show();
  counter++;
}
 });

$('#closingCross').click(function() {
    alert("hello");
 });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [delegated event handler](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Change:

```
$('#closingCross').click(function() {
```

to:

```
$(document).on('click', '.closingCross', function(e) {
```

The snippet:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.closingCross', function(e) {
  console.log("hello");
});


$(document).ready(function(){

  var counter=0;

  $('.one').click(function() {
    if(counter <= 0){
      $('p').append( "<p class='closingCross'>X</p>" );
      counter++;
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="one">
    <p>
        hello world
    </p>


</div>
```

Comment: please have a look at my updated version on fiddle  - https://jsfiddle.net/foba81eb/4/ still having issues with reopening! Cheers for the help!

Comment: @user3502952 Could you explain what do you intend for reopening?

Comment: I want create an overlay menu system for my site. User clicks the hamburger icon and then meun / overlay appears with the X and then you click that which will remove that - does that make sense?

Comment: I have this as an example but I want to overlay the whole screen http://www.badassembly.com/ thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is append the event to an already created element in the DOM.

```
$('#topp').on('click', 'p', function() {
    alert("hello");
 });
```

Your working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/foba81eb/4/